# init scripts don't run

Tags: 16.04, init.d, init

I wish to create a script that will run on startup of runlevel 3 only once.
Therefore now I perform tests to see if the execution really works.

I tried to create a file at `/etc/init.d/myscript` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT="/dev/tty1"

echo -e "Hello world!" > $OUT

ps auxf > /path_to_some_folder/_script_ps_auxf.txt
runlevel > /path_to_some_folder/_runlevel.txt
id -u > /path_to_some_folder/id.txt
pwd > /path_to_some_folder/pwd.txt
```

That file has execution bit enabled for all users (ugo).
Also I created a symbolic link to `/etc/init.d/myscript` at `/etc/rc3.d/S99myscript`.
Then I:

1. logout of my user.
2. press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F2` in order to see `tty2`.
3. Log in to my user and `sudo service lightdm stop` in order to disable GUI.
4. Then `sudo init 3` in order to be at runlevel 3.

But the files at `/path_to_some_folder/` don't exist after the `init 3`. Why?

---

I tried also several other variations of the above - including usage of `update-rc.d`.

---

In addition I tried to edit `/etc/rc.local` such that the code in `/etc/init.d/myscript` is embedded to `/etc/rc.local` prior to the `exit 0` line, but still nothing happens (no file is created).

---

### Update 6 Oct , 18:00 UTC:

For some reason now I can see all the files in the directory `/path_to_some_folder/`:
(I added to all files an underscore `_` in order to distinguish them better from other files)

```
$ ls /path_to_some_folder/_*
/path_to_some_folder/_id.txt  /path_to_some_folder/_pwd.txt  /path_to_some_folder/_runlevel.txt  /path_to_some_folder/_script_ps_auxf.txt
```

By inspection of their time, they're all created when the system is powered on.

By inspection of the file `/path_to_some_folder/_script_ps_auxf.txt`, I noticed that the init process was started:

```
/bin/bash /etc/init.d/myscript start
```

Therefore I understand that the init scripts work.
Indeed, when I press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` in order to see `tty1`, I notice the text "Hello world!" at the top (prior to the login prompt).

The only problem is to realize:

1. Why do they work now?
2. Why the script is executed on the default runlevel of Ubuntu 16.04 ?
   They should be executed only at runlevel 3, see:

   ```
   $ ls -1 /etc/rc*.d/*myscript*
   /etc/rc3.d/S99myscript
   ```

Answering question #1 myself:
I *suspect* that a restart was required in order for the init scripts to work.

About question #2:

The file `/etc/inittab` doesn't exists, therefore it can't determine the runlevel:

```
$ ls /etc/inittab
ls: cannot access '/etc/inittab': No such file or directory
```

The default runlevel, according to `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`, is `2`:

```
$ grep -m 1 DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL= /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

There are no kernel command lines parameters according to the file `/etc/default/grub`:

```
$ less /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

When I power on my PC and login to my user, I notice that my runlevel is `5`:

```
$ runlevel
N 5
```

My script was supposed to run at runlevel 3 **only**.

Any ideas what's going on?

---

### Update 6 Oct, 18:40 UTC:

I understand now - Ubuntu's runlevel differ from the standards, see:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels

This means that runlevels `2` to `5` are all the same:

> Graphical multi-user plus networking (DEFAULT)

Comment: `/path_to_some_folder/` isn't mounted yet? Is `/path_to_some_folder/` your encrypted `$HOME`?

Comment: @waltinator That folder is mounted. It's not encrypted. (When the file-system mounting process is performed?)

Comment: Try typing the commands in by hand. Maybe an error message will be displayed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Please see my update.

Comment: @waltinator Please see my update.

Comment: But `man inittab` says `The Upstart init(8) daemon does not use this file, and instead reads its configuration from files in /etc/init.  See init(5) for more details.`

Comment: @waltinator I don't have manual entry for `inittab`. My Ubuntu version is 16.04. By inspection of the file `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`, I see that it tries to read the file `/etc/inittab` and tries to extract the default runlevel from it.

Answer (score 5):

> I understand now - Ubuntu's runlevel differ from the standards, see: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels

No, actually you don't understand.

You're working with a mental model of the operating system that has twice been superseded on Ubuntu.  Upstart was introduced a fair few years ago; and the version that you are using now (16.04) has superseded even *that*.

You are using Ubuntu 16.04, a systemd operating system.  Run levels are "obsolete" according to the systemd doco.  You can forget about them.  The *Upstart Cookbook* and the manual pages for upstart's `init` do not apply (unless you have explicitly switched back to upstart).

You don't need to mess around with `/etc/rc.local`.  That's from the `rc` system that *preceded* the van Smoorenburg `rc` system that you are erroneously thinking you are using now.  It's a mechanism that has been superseded *three* times.  `/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past, too.  Ubuntu hasn't had van Smoorenburg `init` for a decade.

You're using Ubuntu 16.04.  Don't begin with Version 6 UNIX `rc` or van Smoorenburg `rc`; be wary of beginning with upstart job files; forget about van Smoorenburg `init`; and forget about run levels.  Make a systemd service unit, and learn about targets.

(Or install daemontools, or daemontools-encore, or freedt, or runit, or nosh, or perp, or s6, and learn about daemontools-style services.)

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204075/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247543/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/618138/43344
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211927/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200281/5132