# why does update-rc.d not accept my init script

Tags: 16.04, scripts, startup, init.d

I want to start the `noip.com` dyndns client on bootup and am using the provided debian.noip2.sh script (which starts the client from the shell just fine). I copied it to `/etc/init.d`, made it owned by root and gave it `755` permissions. Now when I want to install it, I get:

```
# update-rc.d debian.noip2.sh defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K01debian.noip2.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'debian.noip2.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'noip' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
```

the script looks like:

```
# cat /etc/init.d/debian.noip2.sh 
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/noip2.sh

# Supplied by no-ip.com
# Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Eivind L. Rygge <eivind@rygge.org>
# corrected 1-17-2004 by Alex Docauer <alex@docauer.net>

# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc

DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/noip2
NAME=noip2

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

case "$1" in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting dynamic address update: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON
    echo "noip2."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down dynamic address update:"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry 30 --exec $DAEMON
    echo "noip2."
    ;;

    restart)
    echo -n "Restarting dynamic address update: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry 30 --exec $DAEMON
    start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON
    echo "noip2."
    ;;

    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

How do I get this fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I get this fixed?

Throw it away entirely.  You don't need it in any form.

Then stop trying to use an `rc` system that has been twice superseded on Ubuntu, too.  You don't need `update-rc.d` here, either.

It is now 2016, and the first rule for migrating to systemd applies.  Someone has already done it.  In this particular case, [Michael Nikitochkin did it a year ago](https://gist.github.com/miry/b027edccce70254a6258#file-noip2-service), amongst others (such as [Jeroen Doggen](https://github.com/jeroendoggen/scripts-tools-misc/tree/master/noip2), [Efstathios Iosifidis](https://lizards.opensuse.org/tag/no-ip/), and [some nameless people](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/1hb8lk/starting_a_script_on_boot/casprs8)):

```
[Unit]
Description=NOIP Dynamic IP
Documentation=https://askubuntu.com/a/835318/43344

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/noip2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Further reading

- https://askubuntu.com/a/626858/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/834323/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/617822/43344

Comment: That answer would be helpful, *if* it named the place, format, type, extension, whatever of the file which is above supposed to be. Where the heck does this go? For the rc.d scripts, people know. If they are to improve, please let them know *how*. Like, giving a canonical link to what this is, how it is defined, and where the files go.

Comment: The further reading and the hyperlinked instances where this has already been done all give that.  It's usually a good idea to read the further reading.

Comment: This is close to a link-only answer. At least the links are domain-internal, meaning they are probably not going 404 anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to create a systemd startup script:

```
debian.noip2.service
```

And place it into `/etc/systemd/system/` directory.

One example of such systemd startup script is the following:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/debian.noip2.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After: Instructs systemd on when the script should be run. In our case the script will run after network has started.

ExecStart: This field provides a full path the actual script to be execute.

WantedBy: Into what boot target the systemd unit should be installed

Configure and Install:

Open a terminal and run:

```
exec sudo -i
cp debian.noip2.sh /usr/local/bin/
chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/debian.noip2.sh
chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/debian.noip2.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable debian.noip2.service
```

[Source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html)